# MathJax equations are not displayed on my new site but work fine on its exact copy

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mathjax

## The problem

I am in the process of migrating my website to another webserver.

The problem is that on my new site the LaTeX equations are not displayed.

## The configuration

1. I used Wordpress plugin "Duplicator" to copy my site from one server to another.
2. I have the exact same plugins on each website and the exact same configuration.

I use the plugin **LaTeX for WordPress** to display the equations:

Both of them are using the CDN from MathJax.

## What I tried

- I tried to change the CDN on the new site and it did not work
- I tried running http or https versions of the CDN and it did not change anything
- I tried running a simple html page with the CDN and the equation displayed correctly, telling me it does not seems to be CDN related.
- I tried to clear the cache of my browser, I tried to use different browsers, no difference

So I though it was because of the plugin:

- I tried disabling every plugin except the LaTex for Wordpress plugin and it did not work
- I compared each php file of the plugin between the two versions and they have the same content
- The configuration of the plugin is strictly the same
- I tried comparing the generated html code between the two pages and I see that there is 8 MathJax related style in the old site, and only 5 on the new site.

The style for the classes:

```
 .MathJax_Preview 
 .MathJax_Hover_Frame 
 .MathJax_Display
 #MathJax_About
 #MathJax_Zoom
```

But in the working version there are also the styles for the classes:

```
.MathJax_Preview .MJXf-math 
.MJX_Assistive_MathML
.MJXp-script
```

Moreover I found that the generated html code is different.

Example of the code on a working test page:

```
<script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1">1+x=x^2</script>
```

We can clearly see the math "1+x=x^2" inside the script.

But on the non working page, the math is gone:

```
<script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1"></script></p>
```

When the page load, I can quickly see the preview image being displayed, and then dissapear.

## The Question

What can be the cause of this problem? How can I fix it?

---------------- EDIT -----------------

## The Answer

The problem was with the version of PHP.

I was using PHP 7.1 on the new server and 5.6 on the old one.

The plugin was using regex to make text replacement:

```
$text= preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei',"chr(0x\\1)",$text);
```

By removing the /e flag in each `preg_replace` function it fixed the plugin.

```
$text= preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mi',"chr(0x\\1)",$text);
```

Comment: Thank you! This saved me today.
I also want to add that if you have the "WP Super Cache" plugin installed and enabled, then disable it and empty the cache. That little thing added 30 minutes to my problem solving.
It's probably time to migrate to a different plugin.

Answer (score 1):

**alexandrekow wrote the answer in his question:**

The problem was with the version of PHP.

I was using PHP 7.1 on the new server and 5.6 on the old one.

The plugin was using regex to make text replacement:

```
$text= preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei',"chr(0x\\1)",$text);
```

By removing the /e flag in each `preg_replace` function it fixed the plugin.

```
$text= preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mi',"chr(0x\\1)",$text);
```